# fill the hr:min values in array of objects up to 24 hours back

Tags: javascript, typescript

i have an array of objects which is looks like this

```
{x: "14:33", y: 0}
{x: "14:34", y: 0}
{x: "14:35", y: 1}
{x: "14:36", y: 1}
{x: "14:37", y: 0}
{x: "15:33", y: 0}
{x: "15:34", y: 0}
{x: "15:35", y: 1}
{x: "15:36", y: 1}
{x: "15:37", y: 0}
```

imagine `4: {x: "15:37", y: 0}` is the last element.

**Question:** what is the best way to fill it up to 24 hours back? (with values`{x: "*hr*:*mm*", y: 0}`)

i.e. first element should be `{x: "15:37", y: 0}` (24 hours ago).
Initial array covers few or more hours of time. There might be skipped hours/minutes in initial array, which also need to be filled

**Update:**
Thats my current solution (specifically filling the 24 hours back looks very messy to me):

```
  someFunc() {
    const timeArr = this.get24hrTimeArray(this.data[this.data.length - 1].x);
    this.fill24Hr(timeArr, this.data)
  }

  get24hrTimeArray(lastTime) {
    let arr = [];
    let hours = [];

    const endHr: number = +lastTime.split(':')[0];
    const endMin: number = +lastTime.split(':')[1];

    let hr = endHr;
    for (let i = 0; i < 23; i++) {
      if (hr > 23) {
        hr = 0;
      }
      hours.push(hr);
      hr = hr + 1;
    }
    hours.push(endHr)


    for (let i = 0; i < hours.length; i++) {
      let start = 0;
      let stop = 60;
      if (hours[i] === endHr && i === 0) {
        start = endMin;
      } else if (hours[i] === endHr && i !== 0) {
        stop = endMin + 1;
      }
      for (let j = start; j < stop; j++) {
        if (j < 10) {
          arr.push(`${hours[i]}:0${j}`);
        } else {
          arr.push(`${hours[i]}:${j}`);
        }
      }
    }
    return arr;
  }

  fill24Hr(timeArr, objArr) {
    return timeArr.map(time => {
      const found = objArr.find(e => e.x === time);
      if (found) {
        return ({ x: time, y: found.y });
      } else {
        return ({ x: time, y: 0 });
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Seems like you need a counter. [This link](http://wiki.c2.com/?CounterInManyProgrammingLanguages) provides the code for the most basic counter. From there, it should be straightforward to modify and suit it to your needs. Is it the counter itself you have problems with or writing the counter results to a partially filled array?

Comment: just thinking about the efficient way and implementation. current though is to get the first object's time based on the latest, generate the `hr:mm` array for that time period and compare it with the existing array. this will be a bit messy -> maybe there is a better approach.

Comment: Since we are talking about an array of only 1440 (24*60) elements, I don't think time complexity should be a concern. I suggest you implement that part and then rewrite your question to focus on the more interesting problem (checking for already inserted elements). Maybe putting the original data into a `Map` can help for that problem.

Comment: updated with the sample solution. Checking for inserted elements seems easy for me, but generating 24 hours back is messed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't looping through 1440 minutes, starting from current time and formatting each minute as `hh:mm`, solve the problem?

```js
let now = new Date();
let currentMinuteIndex = now.getHours() * 60 + now.getMinutes(); // number of the current minute

const minutesNumber = 1440; //60*24
let arr = Array(minutesNumber);
for (let i=0; i<minutesNumber; i++) {
  let timeItem = i + currentMinuteIndex;
  let hours = (~~(timeItem/60)%24).toFixed(0); // clamp hours to 0-23 interval
  let minutes = (timeItem%60).toFixed(0); // clamp minutes to 0-59 interval
  arr[i] = {
    x:`${hours.padStart(2,'0')}:${minutes.padStart(2,'0')}`, // add leading zeroes if needed
    y: 0
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That looks much better. the only thing had to adjust is `i<minutesNumber + 1` cause last minute need to be included